# How to ensure the initial snapshot matches expectations?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm relatively new to `Jest` snapshot testing and I'm wondering how to validate the initial snapshot **in a scalable way**? Can someone help me with this?

Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: Just check the contents of snapshot file. Is this what you ask about?

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask! I'm indeed looking for something like that, but are there any more scalable ways to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by scalable?

Comment: I have an application with 5 components (and counting) that I want to snapshot test, hence I want to have (if any) a way to validate all the (initial) snapshots in the most effective way. Hope that helps?

Comment: I'm not aware of any tools that could ease the task but I don't use snapshots much. Basically you need to check that generated HTML corresponds to your expectations with your eyes, I don't see how this can be improved. You may have hard time maintaining snapshots when they are constantly updated so diffing them with Git is a must. FWIW snapshot is a way to make unit test more rigid so it should be validated only when assertions pass. Hope this helps.